# Profile of a deleted account

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I asked and got a StackOverflow account deleted (1 year ago), the questions and answers of that account are still visible with a "user"+userId username, same in chatrooms log, but you have to search deeply with google or the chat search to see them.

Question: isn't there a way to see the old profile page? since all questions/answers are still there it makes sense to keep the profile

Comment: I don't *believe* so. Part of the point of deleting an account is removing the relationship between the posts. The goal is to erase every trace of the person we can without losing the content they've left behind, so I'd be surprised if there was some way. There might be an SEDE query that you could run, but I don't even know about that.

Comment: You could try to find a datadump from when the user still existed.

Comment: cc-by-sa (the copyright (left?) under which all content is covered) specifically prohibits this (section 4.a.).  Users who want out must have their content disassociated from their identities.  The user account page contains information about a person's identity, therefore keeping a copy of that around would be a violation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the old profile is actually deleted, not just "soft-deleted" like posts are. The best you can do is to use Data Explorer to recover the information about posts:

- [Get all posts by deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/112469/get-all-posts-by-deleted-user)
- [Get all answers by a deleted user, together with questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/112470/get-all-answers-by-a-deleted-user-together-with-questions)

(User the default `usernnnnn` name of the deleted user as a Name in these queries.)

If you really want to, you can use SEDE data to reconstruct a part of deleted profile: lists of questions,   answers, comments, and tag scores.

Comment: The Data Explorer threads give both no results, the user is user1125394 (I tried 1125394 too)

Comment: Sorry, the links pointed to `/math/` database because I'm primarily a [math.se] user. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to see the profile page for a deleted account, even moderators get the equivalent of a 404 page.

From what I understand all the posts have their "user id" reset and the entry in the user table is removed so there is nothing to see.